# Sequelize How to customize your our ON condition in a join?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database, sequelize.js

I have these three tables:

```
A:          B:        C:
AId         BId       CId       
b_id                  b_id
```

I want to do this:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*, C.*
FROM A
JOIN B
    ON A.b_id = B.BId
JOIN C
    ON B.BId = C.b_id                        #1
```

I have tried to do this with sequelize like:

```
AModel.findOne({
   attributes: [],
   where: { Aid: idByParameter },
   include: [{
      model: BModel,
      through: {
         // as: 'B', Not necessary
         attributes: []
      },
      include: [{
         model: CModel,
         // on: 'B.BId = C.b_id',             #2
         through: {
            attributes: []
         }
     }]
  }]
}).then((res) => {
  return res;
})
```

The first join, AModel with BModel works correctly because I have set the relation between A and B.

The problem is when I try to make a join between BModel and CModel because the relation is defined in the other side.

Are there any possibility to implement this joint with sequelize??

Sequelize is trying to execute this query:

```
SELECT A.*, B.*, C.*
FROM A
JOIN B
    ON A.b_id = B.BId
JOIN C
    ON B.c_id = C.CId                  #3
```

But I want to change #3 to #1 with something similar to #2.

Is this possible??

Comment: What do you mean by "the relation is defined in the other side"? Can you post your table + relation definitions with?

Comment: Any luck with this, @GutiMac? I'm having a [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41467135/custom-or-override-join-in-sequelize-js).

Comment: Hi @ChrisWright I have responded in your question thread.